# Drag and Drop to Inside a Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a customizable form builder where you can drag and drop the Bootstrap fields into a box in order to make another form. I'm fairly new to html/css/js so anything would be greatly appreciated!

Here's what I have so far:

```html
<!-- FORM START -->
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h3> Preexisting Fields </h3>
      <hr/>

      <!-- First Name -->
      <div id="firstnamedrag" class="form-group" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="textinput">First Name</label>  
        <div class="col-md-9" >
          <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="John"
                 class="form-control pull-right">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Last Name -->
      <div id="lastnamedrag" class="form-group" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="textinput">Last Name</label>  
        <div class="col-md-9" >
          <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Doe"
                 class="form-control input-md">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<!-- INSERT HERE: I want to be able to drag those items above 
                  into the panel and create a new form -->
<div id="builder" class="panel panel-default">
  <h3> Drag Fields </h3> <hr/>
  <div class="panel-body" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <form id="target" class="form-horizontal">
      <fieldset >
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}
function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

Comment: Cool Project. Unfortunately if your new to the game I think that would be quite hard!

Comment: You may want to check this site out http://bootsnipp.com/forms

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be working with some success (see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/z3rk9m32/) or the snippet below)

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}
function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">

<!-- FORM START -->
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h3> Preexisting Fields </h3>
      <hr/>

      <!-- First Name -->
      <div id="firstnamedrag" class="form-group" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="textinput">First Name</label>  
        <div class="col-md-9" >
          <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="John" class="form-control pull-right">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Last Name -->
      <div id="lastnamedrag" class="form-group" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="textinput">Last Name</label>  
        <div class="col-md-9" >
          <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Doe" class="form-control input-md">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<!-- INSERT HERE: i want to be able to drag those items above into the panel and create a new form -->
<div id="builder" class="panel panel-default">
  <h3> Drag Fields </h3> <hr/>
  <div class="panel-body" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <form id="target" class="form-horizontal">
      <fieldset >
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you describe more about the problem you're having? What you're expecting to see vs. what's actually happening?

---

**Note**: I'd also echo D Jones's comment that there's a *huge* amount of work here to build [The General Case](http://xkcd.com/974/).  The urge toward avoiding repetition is a good one, but copy and pasting will help get a handle on some of the common html patterns and idioms in Bootstrap long before you see the time saving benefits of creating an engine to do it for you.

That said, if you do want to explore it as a learning project, I'd take a look at more of the documentation on jQuery UI as that's doing a lot of the heavy lifting here (the Bootstrap html is just an implementation detail):

- [`draggable`](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)
- [`droppable`](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/)
- [`sortable`](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/)